# Ag-Grid: can not read property 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I'm getting **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined** when trying to export ag-grid data into Excel. any idea what could be the reason.
it beaks at line `@_gridOptions.api.getDataAsExce`  in chrome.

```
_exportDataAsExcel: ->
   content = @_gridOptions.api.getDataAsExcel({allColumns: false, exportMode: "xml", suppressTextAsCDATA: true})
workbook = XLSX.read(content, type: 'binary')
xlsxContent = XLSX.write(workbook, bookType: 'xlsx', type: 'base64')
@_downloadXLSX(xlsxContent)


_downloadXLSX: (base64content) ->
fileName = 'export.xlsx'
blobObject = @_base64toBlob(
  base64content,
  'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'
)
```

[image: error screen]